# When i convert java.util.Date to java.sql.Date i mis the time, can i do that convergance with time?

Tags: java, jcomponent

```
java.util.Date tempin = pLabIn.getDate();            
System.out.println(tempin);    

java.util.Date tempout = pLabOut.getDate();   

java.sql.Date labIn = new java.sql.Date(tempin.getTime());    
System.out.println(labIn);    

java.sql.Date labOut = new java.sql.Date(tempout.getTime());
```

The first `System.out` shows `"Thu Feb 27 22:50:06 PKT 2014"`
and the second `"2014-02-27"`

So it miss time. I want to take time as well.

Answer (score 4):

Use a `java.sql.Timestamp` instead.

Comment: i want time and date both

Comment: That's what a timestamp is.

Answer (score 2):

The `toString()` [implementation](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/java/sql/Date.java#Date.toString%28%29) for `java.sql.Date` will only give you the date in the format `year-month-day`.

This is also precised in the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html#toString%28%29):

> Formats a date in the date escape format yyyy-mm-dd.

If you want to keep the time in your print statement, you can use a [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) instead.

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
System.out.println(sdf.format(labIn));
```

Comment: i have to use this "labIn" in oracle db, and there java.util.date does not insert, so i have to convert it to java.sql.date. BUT i need time and date both

Comment: @user3190582 You seems to confond the String representation and the date object itself. The string representation of the date object will only print the year-month-day, but the date object itself won't "loose" the time.

Comment: sorry, i understand what you are saying, but there is problem that in my oracle db table all entries have same time (12:00:00 AM), thats why i thought time is getting missed

Comment: @user3190582 If the time were loosing, I think you will have 00:00:00AM. So the problem might be somewhere else.